# rotating custom image around its center

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have an png image width 200 x height 50 in pixel. I need to rotate it around its center by an angle.

[image]

My onDraw method

```
@Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        initDrawingTools();
        drawRect(canvas);
        drawBack(canvas);
        Matrix mat = new Matrix();
        Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.needle);
        cX = getWidth()/2-bMap.getWidth()/2;
        cY = getHeight()/2-bMap.getHeight()/2;
        mat.setTranslate(cX, cY);
        mat.postRotate(angleSpeed,cX, cY);      
        Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap, 0, 0,bMap.getWidth(),bMap.getHeight(), mat, true);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bMapRotate, mat, null);
    }
```

This is the closest i managed. As i understand the center of image is floating while it is rotating. For example: 0 degree - 200x50, 90 degree 50x200 etc. And in this case its not rotating around its center. Could someone give me some hints or explain how to get the result?

**EDIT working Mikel Pascualc suggestion:**

How to make arrow remain in angled position after animation???

```
seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
               ROTATE_TO = speed;
               spin();}
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                ROTATE_FROM = speed;}
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                speed = progress;
//            textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
//            textView.setText(progress);
            //rodykle.onSpeedChanged((float)progress);
            }
        });
    }
    public void spin(){
        TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView1.setText("From: " + ROTATE_FROM + "\nTo: " + ROTATE_TO + "\nProgress: " + speed);
        ImageView needle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.needle1);
        RotateAnimation r = new RotateAnimation(ROTATE_FROM, ROTATE_TO, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        r.setDuration((long) 2*1000);
        r.setRepeatCount(0);
        r.setFillAfter(true); // <-- ADDED THIS TO STAY IMG IN ANGLE AFTER ANIMATION
        needle.startAnimation(r);
    }
```

Comment: I "think"(not sure), you should not use 'createBitmap' for this, as it not efficient in term of memory use. Once, because of this, I was getting OutOfMemory error

Comment: As it shows here no new bitmap is created???  `public static Bitmap createBitmap (Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height, Matrix m, boolean filter) 
Added in API level 1
Returns an immutable bitmap from subset of the source bitmap, transformed by the optional matrix. The new bitmap may be the same object as source, or a copy may have been made. It is initialized with the same density as the original bitmap. If the source bitmap is immutable and the requested subset is the same as the source bitmap itself, then the source bitmap is returned and no new bitmap is created.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You better use an animation.
Example:

```
public class NeedleRotateActivity extends Activity {
private static final float ROTATE_FROM = 0.0f;
private static final float ROTATE_TO = -10.0f * 360.0f;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ImageView needle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.needle);

    RotateAnimation r = new RotateAnimation(ROTATE_FROM, ROTATE_TO, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    r.setDuration((long) 2*1500);
    r.setRepeatCount(0);
    r.setFillAfter(true);
    needle.startAnimation(r);
}
```

Comment: Animation is working perfect, had some funny time :), but it is not solution because after spin image goes back to the starting angle. I use Seek Bar to adjust `ROTATE_FROM`, `ROTATE_TO`. Added that piece of code to the question

Comment: Just needed to add `r.setFillAfter(true);`. Now the animation remains after turn :) Thanks for advice!

Comment: I'll add that line to the example; most people will want that. Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

I have done a similar thing to this. I rotated a bottle round itself to slowly reduce the speed until it stops. Sharing a piece of code from that, hope it help you.

```
rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(0, 360,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            rotateAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            rotateAnimation.setDuration(duration);
            rotateAnimation.setRepeatCount(0);
            imgBottle.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);

            rotateAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation anim) {
                };

                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation anim) {
                };

                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim) {
                    duration = duration + 70;
                };
            });

imgBottle.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
```